# Why is an iterator empty on a populated-on-demand collection?

Tags: java, tomcat, iterator

I have the following code:

```
for (String helpId : helpTipFragCache.getKeys())
{
    List<HelpTopicFrag> value = helpTipFragCache.getValue(helpId);
    helpTipFrags.put(helpId, value);
}
```

The helpTipFragCache has a mechanism to load the cache if values are needed at it is empty. The getKeys() method triggers this and the cache is loaded when this is called. However in the above case, I see varying behavior.

I first debugged it quickly to see if the cache was indeed populating (within eclipse). I stepped through and the for loop was never entered (due to an empty iterator).

I then debugged it again (with the same code) and stepped into the getKeys() and analyzed the whole process there. It then did everything it was supposed to, the iterator had values to iterate over and there was peace in the console.

I have fixed the issue by changing the code to do this:

```
Set<String> helpIds = helpTipFragCache.getKeys();
helpIds = helpTipFragCache.getKeys();
for (String helpId : helpIds)
{
    List<HelpTopicFrag> value = helpTipFragCache.getValue(helpId);
    helpTipFrags.put(helpId, value);
}
```

Obviously the debugging triggered something to initialize or act differently, does anyone know what causes this? Basically, what is happening to create the iterator from the returned collection?

Some other pertinent information:

- This code is executed on server startup (tomcat)
- This code doesn't behave as expected when executed from an included jar, but does when it is in the same code base
- The collection is a Set

**EDIT**

Additional Code:

```
public Set<String> getKeys() throws Exception
    {
        if (CACHE_TYPE.LOAD_ALL == cacheType)
        {
            //Fake a getValue call to make sure the cache is loaded
            getValue("");
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(cache.keySet());
    }

public final T getValue(String key, Object... singleValueArgs) throws Exception
{
    T retVal = null;
    if (notCaching())
    {
        if (cacheType == CACHE_TYPE.MODIFY_EXISTING_CACHE_AS_YOU_GO)
        {
            retVal = getSingleValue(key, null, singleValueArgs);
        }
        else
        {
            retVal = getSingleValue(key, singleValueArgs);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        synchronized (cache)
        {
            if (needToLoadCache())
            {
                logger.debug("Need to load cache: " +  getCacheName());
                if (cacheType != CACHE_TYPE.MODIFY_EXISTING_CACHE_AS_YOU_GO)
                {
                    Map<String, T> newCache = null;
                    if (cacheType != CACHE_TYPE.MODIFY_EXISTING_CACHE)
                    {
                        newCache = getNewCache();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newCache = cache;
                    }
                    loadCache(newCache);
                    cache = newCache;
                }
                lastUpdatedInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                forceLoadCache = false;
            }
        }
        ...//code in here does not execute for this example, simply gets a value that is already in the cache
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

And back to the original class (where the previous code was posted from):

```
    @Override
    protected void loadCache(
            Map<String, List<HelpTopicFrag>>    newCache)
    throws Exception
    {
        Map<String, List<HelpTopicFrag>> _helpTipFrags = helpDAO.getHelpTopicFrags(getAppName(), _searchIds);
        addDisplayModeToFrags(_helpTipFrags);
        newCache.putAll(_helpTipFrags);
    }
```

Above, a database call is made to get the values to be put in the cache.

Comment: @Timo That's not happening here. The OP's putting elements into a different collection than the one being iterated over.

Comment: @millimoose oh, you're right. sorry

Comment: I'm not sure this is answerable without knowing how the cache is implemented. There isn't any one generally applicable reason why this would behave differently when debugging. The debugger may call some methods (like `.size()`) that your code doesn't to produce debug output, and this method causes the cache to be populated, while `getKeys()` does not. (Or is buggy in a way that requires it to be called twice.)

Comment: @millimoose Does it really matter? The iterator is expected to use the collection given in the loop. The getKeys method resolves to a populated collection, but the iterator is jumping the gun. Regardless, I updated the question.

Comment: @Noremac It might matter because it is a priori highly unlikely that an iterator would just randomly not iterate over a collection when it doesn't feel like. The more likely explanation is that under certain conditions, you're creating an iterator over an empty collection.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to

`Basically, what is happening to create the iterator from the returned collection?`

The `for` loop in your case treats `Set`as [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) and uses an [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) obtained by calling [Iterable.iterator()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#iterator%28%29).

```
Set as = ...;

for (A a : as) {
    doSth ();
}
```

is basically equivalent to

```
Set as = ...;

Iterator hidden = as.iterator ();
while (hidden.hasNext ()) {
    a = hidden.next ();
    doSth ();
}
```

Comment: -1: I fail to see how does this solve the OP's problem. He's not asking for an explanation on how the enhanced for loop works, but why his (unknown) cache implementation is buggy.\

Comment: @millimoose Actually he's asking `Basically, what is happening to create the iterator from the returned collection?`. SO why the downvote?

Comment: Because I disagree with your understanding of the question - the subquestion you're focusing on obviously isn't the cause of the problem. (Both the "broken" and "working" snippet in the question end up ultimately calling the same `iterator()` implementation.) I think that this makes your answer unhelpful.

Comment: @millimoose The subquestion is still a a part of the original question.

Comment: @millimose nevertheless, I asked it and the response is a contribution to my original question, although there may be another cause.